# Element shares classname and dynamically moves Python / BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Several elements have the same class name. The problem I'm having is grabbing the right one when they change location every other page.

Sometimes it's the first one, and everything in-between.

Is there a way to use the text `"CEO"` as a reference to grab the next span text?

I just need the name.

This works when it's in the right location

```
title = find_all("//span[@class='KeyDetail'and text()='CEO']")[3]
name = title.find_all('span')[1].text



<div class="DetailsList">
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
  <div class="KeyDetail">...</div>
    <span class="header">CEO</span>
    <span class="text">Joe Smith</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use find(text='CEO') then locate the element with nextSibling, try the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="DetailsList">' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div> ' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>  ' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<span class="header">Hello</span>' \
       '<span class="text">Joe Smith</span></div> ' \
       '<div class="DetailsList">' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div> ' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>  ' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<div class="KeyDetail">...</div>' \
       '<span class="header">CEO</span>' \
       '<span class="text">Ryan Evans</span></div> '

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    if span.find(text='CEO'):
        ceo_name = span.nextSibling
        print(ceo_name.text)
```

---

*Prints*

> ```
> Ryan Evans
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!